# Add Edges Dynamically to VisJS graph

Tags: vue.js, vis.js

I would like to dynamically create/update a VisJS graph.
I was able to add the nodes, but if I try to add the edges the grapth diappears.

I already tried the solutions listed in this stackoverflow question, none of them worked: [Add Edge Dynamically visjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39701703/add-edge-dynamically-visjs)

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/Janiaje/tb1smgo2/5/

Code fails at this (52) line:

```js
this.edges.add(this.edgesArray)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Large third-party objects or libraries should be initialized without Vue reactivity because it can be a cause of unexpected behavior or performance issues. And this is your case, if you just comment `network` in Vue `data` function(to make `network` field be non-reactive) the app will work.

I also recommend to do that for your vis DataSets.